# My own answer would be a copy of code. Is this good

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I asked this question today: [How to add border to tiled pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034217/how-to-tile-a-pdf-to-multiple-pages-with-a-border).
I also found an answer due to a comment with a link. My preferred way to handle this would be to give the commenter the credit but he correctly states that link only answers are discouraged and says I can post my own solution as an answer (he has no time to make a good answer).
He also pointed out: [Own answers are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

So I could answer this question myself but, and that's my question: It would basically contain copy&paste from the code of the linked example. Only little more.

Would that be still acceptable as I didn't do a "creational change" or is it then better not to answer the question?
The link could be found in the comments.

Comment: The answer isn't from Stack Overflow, so your question doesn't count as a duplicate. If the link in the comment helped to get your problem solved, write an answer with the exact description how, and add the helpful link additionally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you really not explain what the problem is, in words, what the approach of that code is, and how it goes about solving the problem?  If you can't, you probably don't understand the answer well enough to use it, and you should figure all of that information out before doing anything else, and then post it in an answer after you do.

A code only answer is typically going to be a low quality answer.  It would be *an answer*, but not a *valuable* one.